# React Ant design 4 input RTL

Tags: antd, react-typescript

I'm using my react typescript  project for ant design 4,  I want to know how to put ant design input filed to type right to left , anyone know some solution

**[stack blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gket8u?file=index.js)**

**code here**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Input placeholder="Basic usage" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dir='rtl'`

```
<Input placeholder="Basic usage" dir='rtl' />
```